# The error "arrays.h: not such file or directory" using Borgelt's Apriori

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, rules, apriori

I'm using the Borgelt's code of Apriori, with the Cgwin toolchain in Eclipse and Windows 11. But when I want to build the project, it returns the following error: "arrays.h: not such file or directory". That header is not recognized and I don't know why. It is located in the folder util/src. In fact, the file array.c,that is located in the same folder, doesn't recognize its own header array.h. How can I fix that error?

I tried to specify the directory using #include "../util/src/array.h" but the error prevails.

Comment: It happens the same with the Eclat code. The first error it returns is regarding memsys.h, the same problem. But when I build the array.c file, appears also the fatal error related to array.h, explained in my question. It seems the problem is with all the .h files in the folder util. (memsys.h is also there).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is that the compiler is throwing at me this error: fatal error:" ../util/src/arrays.h: No such file or directory". The array.c file doesn' t recognize its own header, and they are in the same folder: util/src.  Someone can tell me how can I fix that problem?